# Couldn't resolve host name in ...

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. У меня есть PHP-скрипт, работающий с VKontakte API. До сегодняшнего дня всё было отлично, а теперь посыпались ошибки:

```
Warning: file_get_contents() function.file-get-contents: Couldn't resolve host name in /api/feed.php on line 45
```

Нагуглить решение у меня не вышло. Собс-но вопрос: что за ошибка, с чем связана и как устранить? Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: DNS не отвалился у сервера?

Comment: Это у тех.поддержки узнать? Я не знаю как проверить. Вчера, кстати, были проблемы с доступом к вконтакту у некоторых российских провайдеров, может с этим связано? Я сам из Беларуси.

Comment: Ну, вчера он в "тетрадь смерти" угодил, угу. Если на хостинге ресурс, то да, спрашивайте у ТП. В общем-то ошибка стандартная, когда DNS лежит. Если, например, прописать ip в коде, то должно заработать, так по крайней мере проверить можно, насколько всё плохо)

Comment: Поддержка ответила:
"возможно блок снят не до конца, нас не пускает к ним

telnet: connect to address 87.240.131.101: Connection timed out
Trying 87.240.131.117...
telnet: connect to address 87.240.131.117: Connection timed out
Trying 2a00:bdc0:3:103:1:0:403:901...
telnet: connect to address 2a00:bdc0:3:103:1:0:403:901: Network is unreachable
Trying 2a00:bdc0:3:103:1:0:403:902...
telnet: connect to address 2a00:bdc0:3:103:1:0:403:902: Network is unreachable"

Предложили подождать до завтра.